# Netbeans Java Build successful but no output

Tags: java, netbeans

Wrote this simple java code:

```
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        a = 5;
        System.out.println("The value of a is" + a);
    }
}
```

All it gives me is:

run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

What's going on? My Eclipse doesn't do this.

Comment: you simply build the project, but did not execute it ?

Comment: This is the only class in my project, so I can't be running another one.

Comment: @ Emerson Cod I pressed the Run button and there is no output. I'm new to java so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Building does not imply running. Right-click on the Java Class in the Project window and choose "Run File".

Comment: I have another project in netbeans and it runs with no problem.

Comment: @Costis Avialis, Yes this worked, but why it doesn't work when I simply click on the green "Run project" button on the top?

Comment: NetBeans has more project types than just "executable."  If you start with for example a Java Library type project, there's no main class recorded for the project and so "run" doesn't do anything.  Check your project type, make sure you have something like Java Desktop Application.

Comment: The green run button runs the main class of your project only if you have changed the "Run" property of the project and defined the "Main Class" Field. Else you can define a Main Project Run-->Set Main Project from the main menu.

Comment: How do I check what's my project type?

Comment: Right click on the project and choose Properties. You have all the settings you need to check and change.

Comment: You possibly have more than 1 main code. You only can run one main code per project. If you have more than one, it will run the first on the list, and ignore the main code you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on NetBeans IDE 11.1, just clean and build the project with "Shift+F11" and then run your project with "F6". That will fix your issue. In some cases, merely restarting the IDE can also do the job.

Comment: Restarting IDE seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To run the program:

- Choose Run > Run Project.

The next figure shows what you should now see.

[image]

Comment: I did that, same thing, no output just giving me the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"

Comment: I have the same problem and nothing online seems to be helpful, most just give the same non-working answer, why would I be asking for a solution if that was the problem? idk

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is still relevant. I have Netbeans 9, Go to

> run -> set project configuration -> customize.

This would open a new window. In that window in the RUN area, please change Main class to the current file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options availble run the project(F6) and Run the File (Shift + F6).

[image]
For mine this worked like this (F6)

F6

> run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Shift + f6

> ```
>  run:
>     Welcome to JavaBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
> ```